# Sequence of operations in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sequence

Doing my code I've encountered some difficulties that I quite don't understand (I'm quite new in Ruby). This is an example

```
temp = []
temp_groups_data = []
search_text_user = %r{AD-|Domain}
groups_data.each do |arr|
  temp_groups_data << arr
  arr.delete_at(0)
  arr.each do |el|
    temp << (el) unless el =~ search_text_user
  end
end
```

When I'm trying to use temp_groups_data array in the next part of code I get an array with deleted value at 0. I don't understand why because this array is created before deteting item so that value shuold be in it, why is not? What the sequence of operations in Ruby is? How to duplicate that array and make it usefull in next part of code?

Comment: Could you show us what `groups_data` looks like? It's a bit hard to follow without seeing its format. Also, could you explain what you're trying to accomplish/what the end result should be? There are a lot of shortcuts in ruby and there is probably a shorter and cleaner way of expressing this.

Comment: groups_data array
`groups_data = [["group1", "user_1", "user_2", "user_3"], ["group3", "user_1"], ["group4", "user_2"]]`
I want to use that array in that form in the next part of code but I still get the new array with deleted item at 0 as is in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arr` in `temp_group_data` and the `arr` you call `delete_at(0)` on are the *same* array. It's the same data being accessed in multiple different ways.

Here's a simplified example of what's happening:

```
x = []
y = [:a, :b]
x << y
p x #=> [[:a, :b]]
y.delete_at(0)
p x #=> [[:b]]
```

The simplest change would just be to copy `arr` before putting it into temp_groups_data

```
temp = []
temp_groups_data = []
search_text_user = %r{AD-|Domain}
groups_data.each do |arr|
  temp_groups_data << arr.dup # this right here
  arr.delete_at(0)
  arr.each do |el|
    temp << (el) unless el =~ search_text_user
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, that's work. So if I good understood operation like that temp_groups_data = groups_data.dup done before each iteration also produce the same array? What should I remember duplicating objects next time, I mean more complicated arrays or hashes?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841444/using-self-dup-but-failing-rspec-test-to-not-modify-original-array) and [my answer to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841444/using-self-dup-but-failing-rspec-test-to-not-modify-original-array/38841559#38841559), they might help explain things better than I can do in a comment.